Prove that there is $X\in M$ such that $X^4+13X=A$


Let $M$ be the ring of real $2\times 2$ matrices.
Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
    0      & 3  \\
    -4       & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$
. Show that $A$ lies in a subring isomorphic to $S$, where $S=\begin{bmatrix}
    a      & -b  \\
    b       & a 
\end{bmatrix}$.
Prove that there is $X\in M$ such that $X^4+13X=A$.


Note: These problems are from Berkeley Problems in Mathematics.
My work: For part 1, I tried to characterize the subring. The subring must contain the identity. So I tried finding other matrices. Also, clearly by the map $\phi (\begin{bmatrix}
    a      & -b  \\
    b       & a 
\end{bmatrix} ) = a+bi$ we get that $S\cong \Bbb{C}$.
For problem 2, We can take $X$ out, we get $X(X^3+13)=A$. But I do not know how to proceed. Maybe we can take hint from the first part and look at the isomorphism images of $A$ and $X, 13$.

$S=\begin{bmatrix}
a      & -b  \
b       & a
\end{bmatrix}$ is an abuse of notation.

For the first question, you were on the right track. You need to prove that the subalgebra $R$ generated by $A$ and $I$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$. Now, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^2-\lambda+12$, which has two complex roots $c\pm id$ ($c=\frac12,d=\frac{\sqrt{47}}2$, but we don't care). By Cayley-Hamilton theorem,
$(A-cI)^2=-d^2I$ hence $J:=\frac{A-cI}d$ satisfies $J^2=-I$. Since $R$ is also the subalgebra generated by $J$, it is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.
The answer to the second question is then immediate: in $\Bbb C$, every polynomial equation of positive degree has a solution. Hence so does the equation $X^4+13X-A=0$ in $R$.

Thank you! I got it.
